# Split bar chart using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a split bar chart, using CSS. What I mean by this is something like this...

```
   _____       __________
 __|____| Text |_________|
|_______| Text |___|__
 |______| Text |______|
```

(Please excuse the crude drawing! I hope it makes sense)

Anyway, the code I have so far creates what I've attached on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEUet/2)

HTML:

```
<dl style="width: 600px">
<dt>2008</dt>
<dd><div id="data-one" class="bar" style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</div></dd>
<dt>2009</dt>
<dd><div id="data-two" class="bar" style="width: 80%">&nbsp;</div></dd>
<dt>2010</dt>
<dd><div id="data-three" class="bar" style="width: 64%">&nbsp;</div></dd>
<dt>2011</dt>
<dd><div id="data-four" class="bar" style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</div></dd>
<dt>2012</dt>
<dd><div id="data-five" class="bar" style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</div></dd>
<dt>2013</dt>
<dd><div id="data-six" class="bar" style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</div></dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dt { 
    float: left; padding: 4px; 
}

.bar {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFC94D;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

I've been playing around with this for hours, but cannot work out how best to put a second bar on the left of the central column of text. The closest I got was getting the two bars on top of each other?! I assume there is a better way of doing this, but I honestly haven't got a clue. Does anybody have a possible solution?

Many thanks,
Dave

Comment: Where is the code to add on the other side ? Btw +1 for crude drawing, fiddle and code :)

Comment: It can be anything really, the code I've posted is basically what I found on a tutorial anyway and isn't what would be used in real-life. You could split the bar charts in to two groups of three... once I've got one chart done, I'm sure I could replicate it. I'm just stuck on how to get the ball rolling.

Comment: well, then why using dt / dd ? Use divs...

Comment: I came up with this pretty quick. There is a better way yo use `clear` im sure you can sort it. Not even sure this is any good but still have a look. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/hWxFG/)

Comment: What’s the sense in using a definition list, if your `DD`s are just empty …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with the description list (`<dl>`, `<dt>`, `<dd>`) makes this a little hard without breaking the HTML flow, but I think I've found a way that works and is mostly fluid.

---

First, add your second bars as additional `<dd>` elements, thereby maintaining proper HTML structure:

```
<dt>2008</dt>
<dd>
    <div id="data-one-left" class="bar" style="width:10%">&nbsp;</div>
</dd>
<dd>
    <div id="data-one-right" class="bar" style="width: 5%">&nbsp;</div>
</dd>
```

Next, center your `<dt>` elements and give them a fluid width and height:

```
dl {
    width: 100%;
}
dt {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 8%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2rem;
}
```

Now give your `<dd>` elements the remaining width and float them left/right:

```
dd {
    width: 46%;
    margin: -2rem;
}
dd:nth-of-type(odd),
dd:nth-of-type(even) div {
    float: left;
}
dd:nth-of-type(even),
dd:nth-of-type(odd) div {
    float: right;
}
```

Here a working [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DEUet/3/).

---

The one thing I do not like about this solution, is that I had to give the `<dd>` elements a negative top margin equal to the height of the `<dt>` elements in order to align things. Maybe someone else can come up with a better way of handling this... I couldn't think of anything.

Comment: Thanks for this - it should at least help me to get the ball rolling if nothing else. Here is what I've got so far after a little bit of modifying... http://jsfiddle.net/DEUet/5/ Obviously it needs some tidying up, but it seems to work fine. As I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to CSS, can I just ask why you didn't like the negative margin?

Comment: It is not so much the negative margin that bothers me, but more that the margin needs to match the height of the DT... thereby creating a dependency. As far as CSS is concerned the negative margin is perfectly ok. Your fiddle is looking great, love the animation you put on it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/jfMTg/

So i put a wrapper and inside, made 3 columns edgeLeft | Center | edgeRight

On the left column added  direction: rtl to make the effect that you want.

```
#wrapper { width:100%;}
#edgesLeft{width:35%; background:#f5f5f5; display:inline-block; direction: rtl;}
#edgesRight{width:35%; background:#f5f5f5; display:inline-block; padding-left:40px;}
#center{width:25%; text-align: center;display:inline-block;}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/E9QF9/
That what you're looking for? I can't really explain the changes as there were a lot - just look at your table and compare the two!  (Basically, the data values are in HTML) E.G

```
<dd>
    <div id="data-six-left" class="bar" style="width: 60%">&nbsp;</div>
</dd>
<dd>
    <div id="data-six-right" class="bar" style="width: 0%">&nbsp;</div>
</dd>
```

Change 60% to the value necessary on the left,
Change 0% to the value necessary on the right.